# ARROW_DOWN IN PROTRACTOR

Tags: protractor

Failed: Cannot read property 'ARROW_DOWN' of undefined

THE CODE :
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN).perform;

Comment: where do you run this command

Comment: the compiler you mean ?

Comment: which file has `browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN).perform;`

Comment: it is the actons.js file
 but i run the configuration file

Comment: thats why I guess. Global variables are not available immediately in the config. The first block where it can be used in `onPrepare` function